# Can't add custom keyboard layout in System preferences

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, internationalization, input-source

I've created the custom keyboard layout using **Ukelele** and save an obtained bundle to /Library/Keyboard Layouts folder.

Unfortunately, when I try to add any new layout in *System Preferences* app (having something in "Keyboard Layouts" folder), it just crashes. Has anyone encountered this issue?

P.S. macOS 10.13.6

Comment: Hehe, now I can push the   +   button, and see that there's "Other" item in the list, but when I choose that "Other" section, Settings app is still crashes

Comment: The problem is still there in another user account

Comment: It's more convinient to upload it to Google Drive: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s0OiBHrLLJIcITlvlJ623zv9usP5YeQS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem installing and using your .bundle once the .icns file is removed.  I think there is something wrong with it.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uh6glqw0u2q5h2l/Russian%20-%20PC%20copy.icns?dl=0) is a new .icns file which I think will fix the problem.  Let us know.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is gone. However, I don't quite understand how was this icon pack made, and also, the icon that menu bar shows with your .icns file is just a black dot on a white canvas.

Comment: @BogdanKolesnik  It's not really a dot, but a very tiny R.  It was made too small.  I converted your .icns to .png and then used an app image2icon to go back.  Will fix the size...

Comment: @BogdanKolesnik I made a larger icon, it's at the same link as the earlier one.

Answer (score 0):

I was having related problem.

1. Prepare custom layout
2. Put to `/Library` or `~/Library`
3. Add my custom layout

**Actual Result:** Custom layout working in VS Code but not in Mail, Reminders, etc. You just can't switch to it.

**Expected Result:** Custom layout is working in all applications

**Solution**:
I was trying different things (reboot, changes in layout, etc.) Then I installed Karabiner-Elements found it useless and removed it; everything started to work as expected. I'm not sure what actually happened,  maybe Karabiner downgraded something in my system.

Answer (score -1):

So, after some investigation, here’s what I’ve found:

1. If you add *.bundle* file to any of the possible folders, System Preferences will crash. BUT, if you add *.keylayout* file instead, it will work!
2. If you add a .keylayout file in *Home/Library/Keyboard Layouts* -> you can add it, it will appear at the layouts list, but you won’t be able to choose your new layout (I read about this bug on this site as well);
3. However, if you add a .keylayout file in *Macintosh HD/Library/Keyboard Layouts* -> everything works correctly.

Summing it up, custom layouts are BUGGY in macOS, but you can add one. However, the reason I wanted to add a custom layout was to change russian flag to a neutral icon (and it’s possible in **Ukelele** using .bundle only, because with .keylayout you’ll see default keyboard icon), so I failed here.

Comment: Yep, I just every time get confused with names of these folders because of russian localisation

Comment: I don't think there is in fact any bug.  .bundle works fine if your .icns file is not botched.  Also you do not need .bundle to have a custom icon, you just put both the .keylayout file and the .icns file in the same folder with same names.